# PhoneGap App - My JavaScript won't load on Android?? It works fine on iOS

Tags: javascript, android

I'm building an app using `PhoneGap` to transfer my `html` into app code,

I have generic `icecast` `javascript` which pulls a song title from a `icecast` radio stream server.

It loads and works fine on the `iOS` app build, but refuses to load on Android app? Does anyone have any idea why that is?

The span shows the currently playing song,
The div shows the recently played songs.

```html
<span class="cc_streaminfo" data-type="song" data-username="247hits">Loading ...</span>
<div class="cc_recenttracks_list" data-username="247hits">Loading ...</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://pollux.shoutca.st/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://pollux.shoutca.st/system/recenttracks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge for it !). Well done a good question. Please show more detail of the error (logcat). Nice use of a snippet. I know PhoneGap very well for Android. Help us help you... details...look at how others do it on this site...it's different to other sites.